# Replacing strings within strings at the same time

Tags: string, recursion

I need to recursively add to a String to build a Fractal with a Lindenmayer system. Anyway, essentially I start with String = "A", and every time I recurse (i.e. I start at a depth of 0 and preform the process as many times as the depth is equal to)

I change every instance of "A" to "BrArB" and every B to "AlBlA". Problem is, every time I do one of these, it adds to what the other one does, and screws up the algorithm.

I start with "A"...
should go to "BrArB"...
then should have "AlBlArBrArBrAlBlA"

but I get alot more than I should for that 3rd step.

Any suggestions? If I could do both at the same time the problem would be solved.

Comment: "but I get alot more than I should for that 3rd step" doesn't contain any useful information. Explain **exactly** what you have done and post  the relevant actual code.

Comment: my spidey senses tell me that your problem is on line 3

Answer (score 0):

Try using map:

```
grammar = {'A': 'BrArB', 'B': 'AlBlA'}

# number of rule substitutions
times = 8

# the starting point
axiom = 'A'

for n in xrange(times)
    axiom = sum( (list(grammar[c]) if c in grammar else [c] for c in axiom), [] )

axiom = ''.join(axiom)
```

At the end you may want to eliminate every non-terminal symbols, by using a filter:

TERMINALS = 'lrf'

axiom = ''.join(c for c in axiom if c in TERMINALS)

Hope it helps!